# Contact form SMTP error 554

Tags: php, email

The recipient email address was wrong on our contact form, so i went in today and altered the PHP file, now i am getting this error:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 554 <info@fdb.uk.com>: Recipient address rejected: Relay access denied in \\nas19ent\Domains\f\fdb.uk.com\user\htdocs\PHP\mail.php on line 10
Error!
```

This is the code i'm using for our contact form:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="This message has been generated from the FDB Electrical Contact page \n Name: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "info@fdb.uk.com";
$subject = "Enquiry From FDB Electrical Website";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header('Location: ../contact2.html');
?>
```

Can anyone let me know whats happening, this is the first php i have written and it worked fine previously.

Comment: The sMTP server that you're sending through is not allowing the mail to go through. Contact your host to find out what restrictions they have.

Comment: Thank you, came in this morning and all test emails had come through and it now appears to be working fine. thanks all :)